# my django project is throwing an value error

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

my django project is throwing a value error
the format of the date is correct but its showing that it does not match the error is :

time data 'Sept. 19, 2022' does not match format '%b. %d, %Y'

can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

just change `sept` to `sep` because DateTime uses normal months' names.